# AHK Remove every second char from variable

Tags: string, autohotkey

I need a code on AHK

I have a variable look like this:

```
CYOMYACHOAYJGUGRYYQNYB
```

I need to get this:

```
YMAHAJURYNB
```

I meen, i need every second char from a variable. Thank in advance

Comment: Please specify language in tags

Answer (score 2):

```
Var := "CYOMYACHOAYJGUGRYYQNYB"

Loop, Parse, Var              ; retrieves each character from the variable, one at a time
{
    If (Mod(A_Index, 2) = 0)  ; If A_Index is even (the remainder after division by 2 is 0)
        NewVar .= A_LoopField ; add the retrieved character to the new variable
}
MsgBox %NewVar%
```

Comment: This is probably the best way to do it, but I wanted to share the other way I found as well. :D

Comment: Except you don't need the braces, in this case . . .  My answer adds an input box for the variable, and saves the result to the clipboard.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me. I am using bit wise to determine if the index of the array of letters, given to me by `StrSplit(TestString)`, is even or odd as I loop through them. I used this [forum](https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/86266-how-can-i-determine-evenodd-solved/) post for the bitwise logic. Then I concatenate if the line is even.  So `if index&1=0` will be true when the number is even, thus giving me every other letter to concatenate into `NewString` with this line `NewString=%NewString%%letter%`. Feel free to uncomment out the message box lines by removing the `;` to better see how the loop parses the array.

```
TestString := "ABCD"
word_array := StrSplit(TestString)
NewString:=""
For index, letter in word_array{
    if index&1=0
    {
        ;MsgBox, %letter% added
        NewString=%NewString%%letter%
        ;Msgbox, %NewString%
    }
}
MsgBox, %NewString%
```

Answer (score 0):

As you don't specify any language, I'll answer in pseudocode:

```
set counter to 1
set result to empty string
for every char in string:
  if counter is even:
    append char to result
  increment counter by 1
```

Comment: Never heard of it. Can you provide a link to some info about that language?

Answer (score 0):

user3419297 beat me to it, but mine is even easier:

```
InputBox, x, What Variable?, Enter Variable:
loop, % StrLen(x)
        If mod(A_Index,2)=0
            y.=substr(x,A_Index,1)
msgbox %y%
Clipboard := y
```

You input the variable in a dialog, and the result is shown, and put in clipboard.  Hth,

EDIT: I like the bitwise logic from Zack Tarr!  Substitute for the "if" above:

```
        If A_Index&1=0
```

The rest is the same.